# Sorl-thumbnail dont create folder in cache

Tags: django, caching, imagefield

I get an error instead of thumbnail

```
`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\developer\\love\\love_prim\\media\\Photo object (11)'
Remote file [Photo object (11)] at [960x339] does not exist
[25/Feb/2023 17:07:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3634
Not Found: /media/cache/e5/e6/e5e60125af238c62ca330679f6c18c56.jpg
[25/Feb/2023 17:07:53] "GET /media/cache/e5/e6/e5e60125af238c62ca330679f6c18c56.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 5065
`
```

Cache directory not created in media folder. The cache directory is not created in the media folder. The image is immediately saved to folder profiles.
[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgUh4.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NJCD.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrkIg.jpg)

Tried to execute commands

```
thumbnail cleanup
```

and

```
thumbnail clear.
```

I also tried to create the cache folder myself with permissions 777. No result.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it didn't matter how the `image` or `sorl-thumbnail` field was created in the profile model. The problem was that `sorl-thumbnail` was looking for the original image in the wrong path.